# How to Detect svn file/folder renames or moves with SharpSvn?

Tags: svn, sharpsvn

How can I to detect subversion file/folder renames or moves when doing comparisons between revisions?  How can I distinguish them from a "normal" add and delete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SvnLogEventArgs has a property ChangedPaths. This property contains the paths changes in that revision. It has an Action, CopyFromPath, CopyFromRevision and Path.

If CopyFromPath and CopyFromRevision are set on the file that was added, it was a copy with history (then there's no related delete action, common when branching), or rename/move (when there is a related delete action).